# WPF deserializing databinded collection

Tags: c#, wpf, serialization, data-binding, binding

I looked up for some questions similar to my problem, but I couldn't figure out the reason why is my code wrong. So,

I have a WPF sample application to demonstrate the problem I have engaged. In this application, there is a class Item:

```
[Serializable]
class Item : ISerializable
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateStamp { get; set; }

    public Item() { }

    public Item(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        ID = (int)info.GetValue("ID", typeof(int));
        Name = (string)info.GetValue("Name", typeof(string));
        DateStamp = (DateTime)info.GetValue("DateStamp", typeof(DateTime));
    }

    public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        info.AddValue("ID", ID);
        info.AddValue("Name", Name);
        info.AddValue("DateStamp", DateStamp);
    }
}
```

Furthermore there is another class named Model. It looks like this:

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<Item> itemsList;

    public ObservableCollection<Item> ItemsList
    {
        get { return itemsList; }
        set
        {
            if (itemsList != value)
            {
                itemsList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ItemsList");
            }
        }
    }

    public Model()
    {
        itemsList = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

There is a main window, with a list box and 3 buttons on it:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private Model model;
    private static int counter = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        model = new Model();
        listBoxItems.ItemsSource = model.ItemsList;
    }

    private void AddMoreSampleItem(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        model.ItemsList.Add(new Item
                      {
                          ID = ++counter,
                          Name = "Sample " + counter,
                          DateStamp = DateTime.Now.Date
                      });
    }

    private void Button1_Click_Serialize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("D:\\sample.qwertyasdf", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            bf.Serialize(stream, model.ItemsList);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }

    private void Button2_Click_Deserialize(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open("D:\\sample.qwertyasdf", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            IFormatter bf = new BinaryFormatter();
            model.ItemsList = (ObservableCollection<Item>)bf.Deserialize(stream);
            stream.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In the window's constructor I set the ItemsSource property of the listbox to the ItemsList property of the "model" object:
**listBoxItems.ItemsSource = model.ItemsList;**

Now, as I think, because of the ItemsList implements the INotyfyPropertyChanged, every time the model.ItemsList property changes its value, it should raise the property change event and the listbox should follow the changes automatically.

But instead, the content of the listbox doesn't change, and when I click the button that adds sample items to the list, it doesnt's seem to react anymore.

The listbox:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBoxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListTemplate}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" Margin="10,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

If someone spots the reason of this fail, please, help me out, I'm stuck with this problem for 4 days now. Seemingly the databinding does not break however, but I'm not sure about it.

Comment: Why are you setting `ItemsSource` two times, in XAML and code behind ? Please remove `ItemsSource` from XAML and see the results.

Comment: Nothing changes. By the way, if I take the `ItemsSource` property out of XAML, how can I define the UpdateSource property in code?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your UI to update when data bound properties are changed then you will need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface *on the items whose properties have changed*. Your model has implemented it, but your `Item` class has not. Therefore, if an `item.Name` property was changed, there would be no update in the UI.

Comment: I've tried it, but it's still wrong. I debugged the deserialization process and it just works fine, the observable collection changes smoothly, but no response on the UI.

Comment: Here's the thing... your data types need to be able to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and your collections need to be of type `ObservableCollection<T>`, but you can't serialize a class that has an `ObservableCollection<T>` in it because its events are marked as non serialized. Kent Boogaart wrote a [nice blog](http://kentb.blogspot.co.uk/2007/11/serializing-observablecollection.html) about this situation. I use separate classes when I need to serialize the data and simply substitute `List<T>` for the `ObservableCollection<T>` collections.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Brilliant. If you write this as an answer comment, I accept it as the answer of this question.:)